# Is this a valid use of HTML IDs?

Tags: html, dom

I have something like this in the html

```
<tr id="cart_item_1">
    <td> 
        <a href="#" id="samename" class="someclass">samename</a>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="cart_item_2">
    <td> 
        <a href="#" id="samename" class="someclass">samename</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Is it OK to use the `samename` id twice because its parent's ID is different or its completely unacceptable to use same IDS anywhere irrespective of the the hierarchy of the elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDs must be unique throughout the document, regardless of parent element.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2:

> id = name [CS]
>
> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

Answer (score 2):

No actually not. Like the name would suggest an ID or identifier needs to be unique. So you can use it to define a singular dom element. It is used for example to designate the page header, opposite some article header, which you would assign a class to. Example:

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Welcome to my website!
</div>
<article class="blogpost">
    <div class="header">
        <h3>My blog post title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        ....
    </div>
</article>
<article class="blogpost">
    <div class="header">
        <h3>My blog post title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        ....
    </div>
</article>
```

Now using css you could assign styles to the page header using `#header { ... }` and to the post header using `.header { .... }`. Styles you assign to the id header won't affect a dom element with a class with the same name, and vice versa.

Basically: use an ID for elements that appear on your site only once, use classes for elements that can appear on your site multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it OK to use the samename id twice because its parent's ID is different

No!

> or its completely unacceptable to use same IDS anywhere irrespective of the the hierarchy of the elements?

Yes.